# Query to know when is the last time stored procedure got executed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there any query to check the last execution time of stored procedure. I believe bunch of stored procedures in our database not getting executed and want to delete them. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are system views that can help you with that information:

```
SELECT  b.name, 
        a.last_execution_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats a 
INNER JOIN sys.objects b 
    ON a.OBJECT_ID = b.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE DB_NAME(a.database_ID) = 'YourDatabaseName'
AND b.name = 'YourStoredProcedure';
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any query to check if at all SP is executed at least once ?

Comment: You need to post new question if you have to ask something different.

Comment: @user3369060 The reason for the new thread is so that people with similar questions can find the answer.  If the answer to "can you check if a SP has been executed at least once" is buried in another question's thread, people might not easily find it.

Comment: One note is that `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` is ephemeral. That is, a server restart will clear it out, as will dropping the procedure from cache. So, there are chances for false negatives (i.e. the query will return "no executions" when there have been), but not false positives.